# Debian (Kali) Distribution Linux: GNOME gone

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, gnome3

I am having problems with GNOME. 2 days ago on my Debian Linux I have installed Steam, with about 50 packages with it. Some of them were xorg drivers. I have already had problems with it, but didn't expect it will happen this time. Once I have installed it, I have rebooted my laptop, and I was really dissapointed when I saw an a console login screen. After logon, I have tried to uninstall Steam and 'apt-get install gnome'. I have downloaded about 1 GB of packages and it still didn't work, at all, now I had the missing dependencies errors, that I can't fix.

update: forgot to mention I use AMD64 Linux, some error pictures:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Can you please post the output of the errors?

Comment: Ok, I'll reboot now, but the only problem now is that I can only take picture of the screen. I will add the information to the topic soon.

Comment: Looks like you added an additional repo to your system that was not intended to be compatible with Kali (eg a newer ubuntu repo).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to remove the repo and apt-get update and then apt-get install -f

Comment: Nope, got an error after apt-get install gnome: dependencies and E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: So any offers here?

Answer (score -2):

If you have aptitude installed, you can use it instead of apt-get to manually sort out dependency issues.